# ESLint like globals in TSLint

Tags: angular, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, eslint, tslint

I'm using device plugin from cordova so I have a line like this `let model = device.model || "";` which causes `Cannot find name 'device'.` error. I think with ESLint I would need to do 
`"eslintConfig": {
  "globals": {
    "device": true
  }
}`

 but what is the TSLint counterpart of that?

Answer (score 13):

I believe the `Cannot find name 'device'.` error is generated by the TypeScript compiler, not by TSLint. To solve the problem of missing the global `device` variable you can write a type definition file. By convention this file is named `globals.d.ts`.

In it, put the following code:

```js
declare let device: Device;

interface Device {
  func: () => void;
  prop: string;
}
```

Replace `func` and `prop` with the functions and properties you expect the device variable to have.

Comment: Where exactly should I put this `globals.d.ts` file?

Comment: @Milkncookiez It needs to be in a location that is picked up by the TypeScript compiler. Commonly it is put in the root source folder.